# How do I permanently remove an Alias from my Shell

Tags: shell, terminal, alias

When I was not near my computer some guy got it and set an Alias for `ls` in my root folder. He set it to `'yes NeverGonnaGiveYouUp'`. So now when im in my root folder and type `ls` I get an infinite loop of NeverGonnaGiveYouUp. It's driving me nuts and I don't know how to get rid of it.

I've already tried `unalias` and `unalias -a` but those just remove it temporarily. Once I close the shell and reopen it it comes back. How do I get rid of this crap?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep -n 'NeverGonnaGiveYouUp' ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile` ? There are some other files to look at too depending on your shell and distro..but this should give us a start..

Comment: That sounds like that rick roll kernel module LOL

Answer (score 26):

If unalias removes the issue (even temporarily) we have confirmation it is an alias. It could be "brute forced" out by adding an unalias ls in ~/.bashrc.

```
echo "unalias ls" >> ~/.bashrc
```

That will get excuted every time bashrc is read and will remove the alias.
That will buy you some peace but will not resolve the actual issue that some file is still containing code to re-start the alias. You need to find which file contains the problem.

If using bash:

```
grep "NeverGonnaGiveYouUp" /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc \
      ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile \
      /root/.bashrc /root/.bash_profile /root/.profile
```

That's a good list of possible files that got the definition. If nothing shows up in that search, or you use some other shell, let us know to further help.

Answer (score 18):

unalias command turned off alias for the duration of the current login session. the alias is not removed by unalias command from the .bashrc file, when the user logs in again, that alias is again in effect.

.bashrc is a hidden file, You can check the list of alias by typing:

```
$ alias
```

Check shell configuration file ~/.bashrc and you can remove required alias permanently:

```
 vi ~/.bashrc
```

To find Alias:

```
  $ type --all ls
```

Remove an alias:

```
unalias gs
```

More at [Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/unalias.1posix.html)

**Note**: *unalias -a* will remove all alias definitions from the current shell execution environment.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
you can use following command

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_aliases
```

Comment: That will remove anything defined in `~/.bash_aliases`, not just the `ls` alias (which might not even be defined there anyway).